# Timer Job is missing under Job Definitions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-timer-job

Let me explain clear scenario here, actually timer job was showing under job definitions and was working fine but problem raised when i tried to redeploy the updated solution.

First I uninstalled and removed the solution from CA but the Timer Job was showing under Job Definitions even after removing the solution so I used below command to delete the job completely and then I redeployed the updated solution and activated the feature and now the job is missing.

stsadm.exe -o deleteconfigurationobject -id <>

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: assuming that the feature is responsible of creating the timerjob, try the following: restart the owstimer process, deactivate the feature, restart the owstimer process, reactivate the feature. I think that you may be experiencing some caching related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `stsadm -o deleteconfigurationobject` is not supported outside of PSS guidance.

That said, did you restart owstimer on your server(s) after retraction? This is required with Timer Jobs as the .NET assembly from your Timer Job will still be loaded into the owstimer process.